# How to find the minimum Hamming distance?

Tags: list-manipulation, distance

I have a vector $v = (9, 2, 3, 4, 8)$.

Vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ is generated by a set:
$e_{1} = (4, 2, 0, 0, 1)$,
$e_{2} = (1, 9, 0, 1, 0)$,  $e_{3} = (5, 0, 1, 0, 0)$, $e_{4} = (0, 7, 0, 0, 0)$, $e_{5} = (6, 0, 2, 4, 9)$.

I want to find the minimum Hamming distance between $v$ vector and any vector from given vector space.

My only idea is to make 5 nested loops, which would generate all vectors from the vector space and compute Hamming distance between every single wector and $v$.

How can I make this better?

Comment: (1) Generate a nicer basis using `RowReduce[basis,Modulus->11]`. (2) In future please post actual code e.g. the basis generators in copy/pastable format.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thank you for your valuable comment. See the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, since

```
Mod[Det[{{4, 2, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 9, 0, 1, 0}, {5, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 7, 0, 
0, 0}, {6, 0, 2, 4, 9}}], 11]
```

> `0`

, this space is not whole $\mathbb{ Z}_{11}^5$. We form that space as a finite set of linear combinations of the vectors `{4, 2, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 9, 0, 1, 0}, {5, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 7, 0, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 2, 4, 9}`  by $\mod_{11}$

```
Partition[Flatten[Table[Mod[a*{4, 2, 0, 0, 1} + b*{1, 9, 0, 1, 0} + c*{5, 0, 1, 0, 0} + 
d*{0, 7, 0, 0, 0} + e*{6, 0, 2, 4, 9}, 11], {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}, {c , 0, 10},
{d, 0, 10}, {e, 0, 10}]], 5]
```

Then we map `HammingDistance` from `{9, 2, 3, 4, 8}` on that set and find the minimum distance by

```
Min[Map[Function[y, HammingDistance[{9, 2, 3, 4, 8}, y]], 
Partition[Flatten[Table[ Mod[a*{4, 2, 0, 0, 1} + b*{1, 9, 0, 1, 0} + c*{5, 0, 1, 0, 0} + 
d*{0, 7, 0, 0, 0} + e*{6, 0, 2, 4, 9}, 11], {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}, {c, 0, 10}, {d, 0, 10}, 
{e, 0, 10}]], 5]]]
```

> `1`

Addition.Following the helpful comment by @DanielLichtblau, we may somewhat improve the code, finding a basis of the space under consideration which consists of four elements

```
RowReduce[{{4, 2, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 9, 0, 1, 0}, {5, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 7, 
0, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 2, 4, 9}}, Modulus -> 11][[1 ;; 4]]
```

> `{{1,0,0,0,3},{0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,7},{0,0,0,1,8}}`

and then

```
Min[Map[Function[y, HammingDistance[{9, 2, 3, 4, 8}, y]],Partition[Flatten[
Table[Mod[a*{1, 0, 0, 0, 3} + b*{0, 1, 0, 0, 0} + c*{0, 1, 0, 0, 7} + d*{0, 0, 0, 1, 8}, 11], {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}, {c, 0, 
   10}, {d, 0, 10}]], 5]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.0674779, 1}`

Comment: The execution of the latest code on my antique comp takes 0.845529 sec.

Comment: If there were an analog of [RowSpace](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra/RowSpace) command of Maple in Mathematica, the code could be more efficient.